# How to include timezones for ngx-formly for Angular?

Tags: angular, ngx-formly

I am currently created in my library, named *lib-datepicker*, a component that uses *ngx-formly* for the *datepicker*

Then I have an application named *Survey* which uses *lib-datepicker* which have two dates named: **BeginDate** and **EndDate**.

The **EndDate** have a *minDate* which uses the **BeginDate** like this:

```
{
  "type": "datepicker",
  "key": "EndDate",
  "templateOptions": {
     "label": "End Date",
     "required": true,
     "minDate": "BeginDate"
  }
```

The **BeginDate** is a normal *date-picker* like this:

```
 {
  "type": "datepicker",
  "key": "BeginDate",
  "templateOptions": {
     "label": "Begin Date",
     "required": true,
     "minDate": "2000-01-01"
  }
```

I am currently having problems getting the **BeginDate** for the *minDate* for my **EndDate** which is currently showing one less day.

If my **BeginDate** is "01-10-2020", my **EndDate** is "01-09-2020", this accepts the form as valid and let me submit the dates.

I've been told that the timezone affects the minDate for this setup.

How can I include timezones for both so that they will have the same timezones?